# Why does jquery addClass not change the css

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the "active" class setting to change the color via css.

My question is why doesn't the color of these components change when I add/remove the "active" class using jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#create_links_tab').click(function(){
        $('#share_links_tab').removeClass("active");
        $('#create_links_tab').addClass("active");
        $('#share_links_panel').hide();
        $('#create_links_panel').fadeIn(1500);
    });

    $('#share_links_tab').click(function(){
        $('#create_links_tab').removeClass("active");
        $('#share_links_tab').addClass("active");
        $('#create_links_panel').hide();
        $('#share_links_panel').fadeIn(1500);
    }); 

});
```

html:

```
//left menu
echo "<div class=\"col-md-3\">";
echo "<ul class=\"nav nav-pills nav-stacked\">";
echo "<li class=\"active\"><a id=\"create_links_tab\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Links</a></li>";
echo "<li><a id=\"share_links_tab\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\"><i class=\"fa fa-search\"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Share Links</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

css:

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #428bca;
}
```

Comment: Your title says it doesn't change but your description says it does. Which are you asking?

Comment: @Arun P Johny - I have defined a css rule. It applies different colors when the page loads. It just doesn't change dynamically when I use jquery to add or remove the class.

Comment: Could we see some CSS?

Comment: then it might have to do with [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: It might be that some rules have higher priority in others. That's what makes CSS so wonderful - it cascades from most important to least.

Comment: do you have any css rules using the id selector

Comment: no css rules using the id selector. Just using standard bootstrap css rules.

Comment: you need to share the html and the css rules for us to see what is happening

Comment: You need to show us the CSS rules for the `.active` class you are using.

Comment: @Brett - ok all info added

Comment: You should be able to use Developer Tools to see where the style of an element is coming from. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `active` class must be assigned to the `li` element, in your case it is the parent of the `share_links_tab` and `create_links_tab` elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#create_links_tab').click(function () {
        $('#share_links_tab').parent().removeClass("active");
        $('#create_links_tab').parent().addClass("active");
        $('#share_links_panel').hide();
        $('#create_links_panel').fadeIn(1500);
    });

    $('#share_links_tab').click(function () {
        $('#create_links_tab').parent().removeClass("active");
        $('#share_links_tab').parent().addClass("active");
        $('#create_links_panel').hide();
        $('#share_links_panel').fadeIn(1500);
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mhhy2/)

Answer (score 3):

You're changing the classes of the `<a>` elements, while according to your CSS you should be changing the classes of the `<li>` element inside which the `<a>` resides.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have in your `CSS`, your `.active` class.

For example:

```
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

And then, with jQuery, toggle your class, using the `.toggleClass()` method. Like this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/f5ed7/1/) that I've created for you that show this behavior.